# load data from package treemap

Tags: r, treemap

I have problem installing packages treemap and loading the data "GNI2014".
any help please.

```
install.packages("treemap")
```

Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds':  HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Installing package into ‘\storage.slu.se/Home$/asht0001/My Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/treemap_2.4-2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 173712 bytes (169 KB)
downloaded 169 KB

package ‘treemap’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\asht0001\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp4Eikc3\downloaded_packages

> devtools::install_github("treemap", user="mtennekes", subdir="pkg",ref="5ca7c0b562e4a60bab111752210d6aba8995f55a")
>   Downloading GitHub repo mtennekes/treemap@5ca7c0b562e4a60bab111752210d6aba8995f55a
>   from URL https://api.github.com/repos/mtennekes/treemap/zipball/5ca7c0b562e4a60bab111752210d6aba8995f55a
>   Installing treemap
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD  \
>     INSTALL  \
>     "C:/Users/asht0001/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp4Eikc3/devtools1a8c71612657/mtennekes-treemap-5ca7c0b/pkg"  \
>     --library="\storage.slu.se/Home$/asht0001/My Documents/R/win-library/3.4" --install-tests

- installing *source* package 'treemap' ...
  ** R
  ** data
  ** preparing package for lazy loading
  Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called 'xtable'
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'treemap'
- removing '\storage.slu.se/Home$/asht0001/My Documents/R/win-library/3.4/treemap'
- restoring previous '\storage.slu.se/Home$/asht0001/My Documents/R/win-library/3.4/treemap'
  In R CMD INSTALL
  Installation failed: Command failed (1)
  Warning message:
  Username parameter is deprecated. Please use mtennekes/treemap

  > library(treemap)
  >   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘treemap’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
  >   there is no package called ‘xtable’
  >   In addition: Warning message:
  >   package ‘treemap’ was built under R version 3.4.4 
  >   data(GNI2014)
  >   Warning message:
  >   In data(GNI2014) : data set ‘GNI2014’ not found

Comment: What happens when you install the package xtable?

Comment: gives errors as above (cannot open URL) and does not load the data (GNI2014)